# Is there a simple method of turning a global var into a local var?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have a function that looks like this:

```
const fn = () => x;
```

This function should return the value of `x` where `x` is available in the global scope. Initially this is `undefined` but if we define `x`:

```
const x = 42;
```

Then we can expect `fn` to return `42`.

Now let's say we wanted to render `fn` as a string. In JavaScript we have `toString` for this purpose. However let's also say we wanted to eventually execute `fn` in a new context (i.e. using `eval`) and so any global references it uses should be internalized either before or during our call to `toString`.

How can we make `x` a local variable whose value reflects the global value of `x` at the time we convert `fn` to a string? **Assume we cannot know `x` is named `x`.** That said we can assume the variables are contained in the same module.

Comment: Like `fn.toString () => \`(...args) => { const x = ${JSON.stringify(window.x)}; return ${this.toString()}(...args); }\`;` ? Or if you really just want to capture the return value of the function: `fn.toString = () => \`() => ${JSON.stringify(this())}\`;`.

Comment: How much effort do you want to put into this? It's easy if you know which variables to capture. It's also easy if you just capture the output (if the function doesn't take any input and has no side effects, then suffices). If you really want to run the function while fixing the values of its free variables but you don't know the name of the free variables, then you have to find the names first. You can do this by parsing the string representation of the function and use a tool such as https://github.com/estools/escope to find free variables.

Comment: @FelixKling at some point it will be worth a decent amount of effort. For the time being we can duplicate the variables within individual functions--this isn't a nice approach, but it does what we need. Obviously if there's a better method we'd like to employ it!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. If `x` is a global constant, no matter in which context you `eval` your `fn`, its always going to get the value of `x`. Isn't it? In that case why do you want to internalize `x`?

Comment: Could you change x to a parameter and bind it to the function's parameters before converting it to a string? fn = fn.bind(this, x) and changing the function initialization to fn = (x) => x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot know `x` is named `x`. This is the central piece of this puzzle and is therefore bolded in the original question. While it would be nice if we had a simpler solution, it does seem a proper answer here comes down to implementing some kind of parser or AST traversal.

Why is this necessary? While we can make the assumption that `x` lives in a module as a global (it's necessarily shared between functions), we cannot assume it has a known name. So then we need some way of extracting `x` (or all globals really) from our module and then providing it as context when we eventually `eval`.

N.B.: providing known variables as context is trivial. Several answers here seem to assume that's a difficult problem but in fact it's quite easy to do with `eval`; simply prepend the context as a string.

So then what's the correct answer here? If we were to use an AST ([Acorn](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn) may be a viable starting point, for instance) we could examine the module and programmatically extract all the globals therein. This includes `x` or any other variable that might be shared between our functions; we can even inspect the functions to determine which variables are necessary for their execution.

Again the hope in asking this question originally was to distill a simpler solution or uncover prior art that might be adapted to fit our needs. Ultimately my answer and the answer I'm accepting comes down to the nontrivial task of parsing and extracting globals from a JavaScript module; there doesn't appear to be a simple way. I think this is a fair answer if not a practical one for us to implement today. (We will however address this later as our project grows.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want *lock* certain variables while converting function to string, you have to pass that variables along the stringified function.

It could be implemented like this (written with types -- typescript notation)

```
const prepareForEval = 
  (fn: Function, variablesToLock: { [varName: string]: any }): string => {
    const stringifiedVariables = Object.keys(variablesToLock)
        .map(varName => `var ${varName}=${JSON.stringify(variablesToLock[varName])};`);

    return stringifiedVariables.join("") + fn.toString();
  }
```

Then use it like this

```
const stringifiedFunction = prepareForEval(someFunction, { x: x, y: y })

// you can even simplify declaration of object, in ES6 you simply write
const stringifiedFunction = prepareForEval(someFunction, { x, y })
// all variables you write into curly braces will be stringified
// and therefor "locked" in time you call prepareForEval()
```

Any `eval` will declare stringified variables and funtion in place, where it was executed. This could be problem, you might redeclare some variable to new, unknown value, you must know the name of stringified function to be able to call it or it can produce an error, if you redeclare already declared `const` variable.

To overcome that issue, you shall implement the stringified function as immediatelly executed anonymous function with its own scope, like

```
const prepareForEval = 
  (fn: Function, variablesToLock: { [varName: string]: any }): string => {
    const stringifiedVariables = Object.keys(variablesToLock)
        .map(varName => `var ${varName}=${JSON.stringify(variablesToLock[varName])};`);

    return `
      var ${fn.name} = (function() {
        ${stringifiedVariables.join("")}
        return ${fn.toString()};
      )(); 
    `;
  }
```

this modification will declare function and variables in separate scope and then it will assign that function to `fn.name` constant. The variables will not polute the scope, where you `eval`, it will just declare new `fn.name` variable and this new variable will be set to deserialized function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` operator `||` to concatenate current value of `x` to `fn.toString()` call

```js
const fn = () => x;
const x = 42;
const _fn = `${fn.toString()} || ${x}`;
console.log(_fn, eval(_fn)());
```

Comment: Try rereading the question: You don't know the name of `x` at the time you serialize the function so your sample doesn't work. A correct answer will almost certainly implement some kind of AST traversal.

Comment: @maxcountryman What do you mean by "You don't know the name of x"? You can call `.toString()` first, then get the "name" of variable identifier following `return` statement at `fn` `const _fn = \`${fn.toString()} || ${window[fn.toString().split(/\s/).pop()]}\``. The original Question does not include the term "AST traversal" or describe requirement as including _"certainly implement some kind of AST traversal"_

Comment: I'd be fascinated to read about how you'd extract `x` from a module without knowing `x` is named thusly? I can imagine one way of doing so is via an AST, but perhaps there are simpler methods available to JS/Node. Unfortunately your answer doesn't address the core issue of actually extracting `x` and simply embeds it in a string once it's apparently been extracted. (This is trivial and something we already do for other context.)

Comment: @maxcountryman _"I'd be fascinated to read about how you'd extract `x` from a module without knowing `x` is named thusly?"_ Would begin by using `.toString()` approach at Answer and comment. Given `javascript` at Question, the Answer appears to meet requirement described at original Question. If not, perhaps ask a new Question specifically requiring AST, or other approaches, and clearly defining parameters; while excluding approaches at present Answers from being possible solutions? Instead of including requirements at comments which do not appear at actual text of original Question.

Comment: The requirement is clearly spelled out in the question. What confuses you about the fact you cannot know `x` is named `x`? Your answer assumes you know `x` is named as such and then proceeds to solve an orthogonal concern--embedding a known variable into a string. Perhaps you did not read the question thoroughly, which is understandable, but you aren't answering the question posed. Thank you for your effort here, but unfortunately it does not help us.

Comment: From perspective here, the Question is not clear, else `fn const _fn = \`${fn.toString()} || ${window[fn.toString().split(/\s/).pop()]}\`` would resolve Question, given `javascript` at OP; where `x` is not specifically referenced, but retrieved from `.toString()` using `RegExp`. If there are detailed parameters not included within text of Question itself, perhaps consider asking a new Question clearly defining the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables can be made local (private) with closures. [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp)

```
function myFunction() {
    var a = 4;
    return a * a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **guest271314**, I now see what you want.

This is his code, just little improved:

```
const stringifiedFn = `
    (function() {           
        const _a = (${fn.toString()})();
        return _a !== undefined ? _a : ${JSON.stringify(fn())};
    })();
`;
```

this code will execute `fn` in context, where you `eval`, and if `fn` in that context returns `undefined`, it returns the output of `fn` in context, where it was stringified.

All credit goes to **guest271314**

Answer (score -1):

do you mean this? only answer can post code, so I use answer

```js
var x = 42

function fn() {
  return x
}


(() => {
  var x = 56
  var localFn = eval('"use strict";(' + fn.toString()+')')
  console.log(localFn)
  console.log(localFn())
})()
```

- why rename to `localFn`, if you use `var fn=xx` in this scope the outer fn never exists!
- in nodejs? refer nodejs vm
- passing context? you can not save js context unless you maintain your own scope like angularjs

Answer (score -1):

If you're already "going there" by using eval() to execute fn() in the new context, then why not define the function itself using eval()?

`eval('const fn = () => ' + x + ';')`